# iPad screen is black and won't turn on after charging and resetting

Tags: ios, ipad, power

Yesterday I dropped my iPad 3 but luckily the screen did not crack. However the screen is now black and will not turn on. I can still here sounds from the iPad. How can I fix this?

What I tried:

- Charging it
- Resetting it (Home+Power)
- Shutting it off

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restoring the device using *iTunes*? If that doesn't work, you may wish to take it into the nearest Apple Store, or finding a place that'll repair your iPad, because if none of the above worked, then I'm afraid your iPad is dead.

Comment: Hi, I tried restoring with iTunes but I get a message saying "Find my iPad" should be turned off

Comment: In that case, enter DFU mode (Google it) and then attempt a restore.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same problem, as has a friend of mine, since we updated our iPhones to OS7. However, I don't recall whether either of us dropped our device or subjected it to shock.

As I recall, I was able to resolve it by powering down and rebooting, but it sounds like you tried that already. You might also try reseating the SIM chip if you've got a model with a cellular connection, and you should probably do so when it's powered down. (I'm not certain whether that matters.) You could also try hooking it up to your computer and doing a reset-and-restore-style operation.